# Help to Code Bowling Like Feature in Unity for Mobile

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, game-mechanics, game-maker

[image]I need Code or Guidelines for Touch Feature. When We Drag ball back and Send it Forward.
I am Making feature like bowling, and I need Player to add force while dragging back and also curve the path of the Ball
Anybody, Please Help

Comment: You're really not giving us enough information. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far, and what are you stuck with?

Comment: I am Making feature like bowling, and I need Player to add force while dragging back and also curve the path of the Ball

Comment: Ok but what have you done, what specific issue are you having..

Comment: I just Don't know Where to Start. I have Seen some codes where the longer you swipe larger the force will be

Comment: Great, so you tried using those code examples you'd seen, right? How did that go? Did you have trouble making them work? If you haven't tried them yet, go [search for something like "swipe throw Unity"](https://www.google.com/search?q=swipe+throw+unity) to find some tutorials / examples / assets you can use as a starting point. Then, if your best efforts with those attempts are not yielding the results you want, you can post here sharing an exact description of what you've done and what about it you want to change.